# how to get all the states from an bidirectional rnn in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bidirectional, lstm

i'm using Tensorflow to  build a bidirectional autoencoder .
in my work  need to access all the states in a sequence and not just the last one but the function 
outputs, state, state = rnn.bidirectional_rnn
just returns the last state f the sequence .
how can i get other states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be don with making another bidirectional rnn just with less layers 
cause the output of this new one would be the states